# Mongobee error: An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongobee

I am using Mongobee for migration, getting exception on `mongoTemplate.insertAll(airports);`

```java
@ChangeLog(order = "001")
public class DbChangeLog001 {
    @ChangeSet(order = "001", id = "seedProduct", author = "San")
    public void seedProduct(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        Product rome = new Product("Name" , "45.9","Desc");
        Product paris = new Product("Name" , "45","Desc");
        Product copenhagen = new Product("Name" , "45","Desc");
        List<Product> airports = Arrays.asList(rome, paris, copenhagen);
        mongoTemplate.insertAll(airports);
    }
}
```

The issue is caused by dependencies, I know, but don't know how to solve the issue:

```groovy
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.4.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'

    compile "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.6"
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.18.2-GA' // workaround for ${javassist.version} placeholder issue*
    compile('com.github.mongobee:mongobee:0.13') {
        exclude group: 'org.mongodb'
    }
}
```

From the Mongobee document there is a [known issue](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee#mongo-java-driver-conflicts):

> **mongobee** depends on `mongo-java-driver`. If your application has mongo-java-driver dependency too, there could be a library conflicts in some cases.

They have shown a workaround method as:

> ```xml
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
>     <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
>     <version>3.0.0</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.github.mongobee</groupId>
>   <artifactId>mongobee</artifactId>
>   <version>0.9</version>
>   <exclusions>
>     <exclusion>
>       <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
>       <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
>     </exclusion>
>   </exclusions>
> </dependency>
> ```

I have followed the same instruction removed the mongodb dependency from Mongobee, but cause me a new error:

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$insertDocumentList$16(MongoTemplate.java:1468)

The following method did not exist:

    'com.mongodb.client.result.InsertManyResult com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertMany(java.util.List)'

The method's class, com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/macbook/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.6/357010b0cdc0e6b2e1fc62e589be4a2c1e0050d1/mongo-java-driver-3.12.6.jar!/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.class
    jar:file:/Users/macbook/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync/4.0.4/3f1538a82a5a8ba8d41f22dd61bb17b30f1a9407/mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.4.jar!/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection: file:/Users/macbook/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.6/357010b0cdc0e6b2e1fc62e589be4a2c1e0050d1/mongo-java-driver-3.12.6.jar
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnsatisfiedDependencyException when creating MongoTemplate bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62893529/unsatisfieddependencyexception-when-creating-mongotemplate-bean)